# Tmux prompt not following normal bash prompt PS1 \W

Tags: bash, tmux

I did some updating on my Mac and seem to have broken some of my settings. I have the following set in my .bash_profile

export PS1="\W $"

This is working in my normal bash session to show just the current directory instead of the 
whole path. However, when I switch into tmux, it again displays the whole path. Other changes to the PS1 in the bash profile such as color or other characters work fine and are reflected in tmux. I have emptied out my .tmux.conf to see if that was causing conflict but there was no change to this behavior.

I did create a new user on the system and tried the same PS1 and it worked perfectly in both a normal session and tmux.

I am mostly confused because I know I had it working and can't figure out what would have changed in the update. What files besides .bash_profile and .tmux.conf could be at play here? Is there a way to tell where tmux is pulling it's settings from?

Additional info:
This behavior is the same in both iTerm2 and Terminal
Tmux version 1.8
Mac OSX 10.9.1

Comment: `tmux` may be creating non-login shells, in which case `.bashrc` would be sourced instead.

Comment: I don't think that is the case as the other aliases in my .bash_profile are carrying over into tmux and any other changes I make to the PS1 reflect properly in tmux however the \W variable just doesn't seem to want to behave normally.

Comment: once you're in tmux, what is $PS1 set to?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Add the following to your `.tmux.conf`:

```
new -n WindowName bash --login
```

You can replace `WindowName` with whatever you want the first window to be named. When `bash` is invoked this way, it sources to your `.bash_profile`, `.bash_rc`, `.profile`, etc. which is where you change your `$PS1`.

Answer (score 40):

This one works for me:
In tmux/terminal:

```
tmux set-option -g default-command bash
```

Or simply put into `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g default-command bash
```

Comment: +1. Yes, still valid under `tmux 2.7`. I spawn several panes automatically everytime I launch `gnome-terminal` by executing `tmux -u new-session \; split-window -h \; split-window -v \; select-pane -t 0 \; send-keys ' ' C-m \;` ... After several solid hours of poring over many many wikis and posts, this finally worked for me.  Cheers.

Comment: Simple, clean, valid.  This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Cbhihe thanks for this tip. But why do you need the send-keys? Without that last part it works for me.

Comment: @SPRBRN: Woaah ! It's been quite some time, but if I recall well `send-keys '  ' C-m` will just send the empty key `' '` with a carriage return to the pane previously selected with `select-pane -t 0`.  So it should position your cursor in said pane in a manner that is visually identifiable. That is the only reason for using it. It's one fewer mouse movement and click ... You can execute the command above (you can even program your term emulator to do so automatically upon launch) and you are set.  Just start typing directly in the pane selected by default, as identified by your cursor.  ;-)

Comment: This is the right answer, but lets point out that first command only works untill you restart the system. So you should use the second command and put it inside your `~/.tmux`.

Comment: For me, none of the ones here worked. But https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/577104 worked.

Answer (score 17):

Add the following in your ~/.tmux.conf

```
set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"
```

From the beloved [ArchWiki tmux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux#256_colors)

Comment: Worked for me. @tmux-lover's one didn't

Answer (score 7):

I have the similar problem. I get the correct result if I always start tmux with the bash command applied, like so:

```
tmux new bash
```

So, to simplify this, I just created an alias in my ~/.bash_aliases file, which I use all the time:

```
alias tn='tmux new bash'
```

This does only work for the first window though. When creating new windows, you have to start bash again, by executing `bash` in the terminal.

Comment: thumbs up man .. the accepted answer didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 7):

Add the following line to `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

Don't forget to save `~/.tmux.conf` and restart `tmux` in order for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and after some research I have added the following command to my `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l /opt/local/bin/bash --login"
```

I am using OSX 10.9.5 with iTerm2 Build 2.0.0.20141103, bash 4.3.30(1)-release, tmux 1.9a.  Bash and tmux are from macports.

Comment: This worked for me, but I also had to run `brew install reattach-to-user-namespace`

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm far late to the party. But here's what worked for me.

I just added `-256color` to TERM.

1. Open/Run tmux.
2. Run the following command: `echo $TERM`. We are gonna use the output of this. I got `screen`. Use your own in the next step.
3. Edit your tmux conf file: `vim ~/.tmux.conf` and add this line: `set -g default-terminal screen-256color`.
4. Exit tmux.
5. Open/Run tmux again.

Using `tmux-256color` didn't work for me. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, bash 4.4.20, tmux 2.6.

Answer (score 1):

Better to detect which terminals are known to the system's `terminfo` database via the `infocmp` command. I've got the following in my `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
# Last match wins
if-shell "infocmp xterm-256color" "set-option -g default-terminal xterm-256color"
if-shell "infocmp screen-256color" "set-option -g default-terminal screen-256color"
if-shell "infocmp tmux" "set-option -g default-terminal tmux"
```

If the `infocmp` shell-command succeeds, then the following `set-option` tmux command is executed.

Answer (score 0):

When using tmux with byobu, you can try the `byobu-prompt` command. It'will ask you whether you want a bash color prompt. After answering Yes, the prompt will change to the usual user@host.